# webstorm coffeescript compiling without .map files

Tags: javascript, dictionary, coffeescript, webstorm, configure

Hy guys, I'm kind of new in webstorm and I was wondering if there was a way to configure it to compile .coffee files to a .js files but without creating a .map file. is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

just in  case and if it helps someone...

```
1) settings/tools/file watchers
2) select edit the coffeescript entry
3) remove the --map parameter in "Arguments" field
```